# Netbeans IDE runtime exception

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, java.lang.class

Good day,

I am self-taught with the help of a few free online courses in Java and very new to everything.

I'm struggling to run a code that's meant to send emails with a set content using my PC as localhost. using Netbeans IDE, I keep getting the following:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement
    at SendEmail$Session.getDefaultInstance(SendEmail.java:29)
    at SendEmail$Session.access$000(SendEmail.java:27)
    at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:16)
C:\Users\ameer.hussein\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)"
```

I'm not sure what to do as I've tried multiple methods to overcome this issue and have a successful application. I've done what I know and can count on from my notes but still dont understand what this exception means.

the code im trying to run:

```
public class SendEmail {

   public static void main(String [] args) {    
      String to = "example@email.com, example@email.com";
      String from = "example@email.com";
      String host = "localhost";
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();


      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);


      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));         
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
         message.setText("This is actual message");         
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
   }


void addRecipients(Message.RecipientType type, Address[] addresses)
   throws MessagingException
```

Can someone please help me understand the exception and why it occurs?

Kind Regards,
Ameer

Comment: You've got a `try` with no `catch` after, try to add this statement.

Comment: Thank you, Will try now and confirm

Comment: I have managed to fix up here and there what i can, however, I'm not too sure why I keep getting this error: 

"Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details."